# 1920x1080 resolution over VGA

Tags: vga

It's been a long time since I've last played with VGA but I know that the standard doesn't just do every resolution out there - I was wondering if the graphics card can support it (computer is an iMac, not an issue) - if a VGA connection can actually handle a resolution of 1920x1080 or if DVI is simply just required.

Comment: VGA can handle almost any resolution that your monitor can support.  The difference between DVI and VGA is that VGA does not send the support resolutions to the port, thus you must select a supported resolution yourself, and could pick an unsupported resolution.  There are differences but there is very little technical reason VGA cannot support even higher resolutions then 1920x1080.  Of course that already is HD so your typical monitor won't get much better then that picture wise.

Comment: Wow, I always thought there was a steeper difference between the two. The more ya know!

Comment: @Ramhound: VGA supports [DDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) - is this not what you mean by "send support resolutions to the port"

Comment: The VGA port-itself has no maximum.  Even with "ancient" graphics (when VGA was predominant), a common 400MHz DAC supported up to 2048x1536.  That was the capability of the chipset.  However, the output resolution was sometimes limited to less than that by the vendor's implementation.  My XP-era computer's on-board graphics (VGA-only), had a chipset that supported 2048x1536, but the  maximum output at the port was 1600x1200.  So you need to look at the specs for your computer to know for sure.

Answer (score 9):

It can handle 1920X1080.  I am using it as I type this

Comment: as long as your display and graphics card supports it..

Answer (score 8):

I am going to assume that with 'VGA' you mean the cable with 15 pins connectors. In which case the answer is **yes**.

There are three cave eats though:

1. Used a good cable. Lower quality cables and high resolution will result in ghosting and other problems
2. Does the monitor support it? It needs to support both the resolution **and** it needs to support it via the DB15 input.  Some devices might not expect such a high resolution via that old port, and if manufacturers can make thing cheaper by catering to the most used stuff then they will do so,
3. The graphics card needs to support this. But you already wrote that this was not a problem.  (Mentioned for the sake of completeness)

Comment: Yeah :) Didn't mean the tiny resolution!

Comment: Those "cave eats" are important.  My television for instance doesn't support anything higher than 800x600 on VGA.  HDMI is a must for higher res.

Comment: There is a typo, is caveats not "cave eats" :)